# Тестирование исключений

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

У меня имеется метод:

```
    protected double getAbsoluteValue(int omega) throws Exception {
    if(omega<-2) throw new Exception("The number is less than 10^-2, current value: "+ pow(10,omega));
    if(omega>3) throw new Exception("The number is more than 10^3, current value: "+ pow(10,omega));
    int a = getTimeConstantInDenominator()* getTimeConstantInDenominator();
    double b = pow(pow(10,omega),2);
    double den =(b * a)+1;
    return numerator/ sqrt(den);
}
```

Я его тестирую с помощью JUnit4.

```
    @org.junit.Test
    public void getAbsoluteValue() throws Exception {
    int omega = 1;
    FilterTest filterTest = new LowPathFilter(1,1,1);
    long actual = (long)filterTest.getAbsoluteValue(omega);
    long expected = (long)(1/Math.sqrt(1*Math.pow(10,2)-1));
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Вот только не могу понять как мне протестировать два исключительных случая.

Comment: ничто не мешает сделать столько тестов, сколько исключительных ситуаций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть хорошая библиотека для ассертов - [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/).

С Assertj тестирование исключений выглядит таким образом :

```
FilterTest filterTest = new LowPathFilter(1,1,1);
assertThatThrownBy(() -> filterTest.getAbsoluteValue(-3))
            .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
            .hasMessageContaining("The number is less than 10^-2, current value: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Тест без проверки сообщения:

```
    @org.junit.Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void shouldThrowException() throws Exception {
        final int invalidValue = -6;
        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();

        yourClass.getAbsoluteValue(invalidValue);

        fail("Тест должен не пройти, если мы не получили ошибку до этой строки");
    }
```

Лучше выкидывать `IllegalArgumentException` вместо `Exception`

Еще один варинт

```
    @org.junit.Test
    public void shouldThrowException() {
        final int invalidValue = -6;
        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
        try {
            yourClass.getAbsoluteValue(invalidValue);
            fail("Тест должен не пройти, если мы раньше не получили ошибку");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.assertEquals(expectedMessage, e.getMessage());            
        }
    }
```

Если есть вожможность лучше искользуйте jUnit5